# helm error when updating: UPGRADE FAILED: The order in patch list

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a problem with helm deployment. It has happend after I have added a new environment variable to the deployment.

When I execute: `helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART]`

I get the following error:

```
Error: The order in patch list:
[
    map[name:APP_ENV value:prod]
    map[name:MAILER_URL value:...] 
    map[name:APP_VERSION value:v0-0-3] 
    map[name:APP_COMMIT_SHA value:...]
]
 doesn't match $setElementOrder list:
[
    map[name:APP_ENV] 
    map[name:COMPOSER_HOME] 
    map[name:PHP_XDEBUG_ENABLED] 
    map[name:DATABASE_DRIVER] 
    map[name:DATABASE_HOST] 
    map[name:DATABASE_NAME] 
    map[name:DATABASE_USER] 
    map[name:SECRET] 
    map[name:INDEX_HOSTS]
    map[name:MAILER_FROM_ADDRESS] 
    map[name:MAILER_FROM_NAME] 
    map[name:UPLOAD_DIR] 
    map[name:ARCHIVE_DIR] 
    map[name:CATALOG_STORAGE_DIR] 
    map[name:ASSET_STORAGE_DIR] 
    map[name:TMP_STORAGE_DIR] 
    map[name:UPLOAD_TMP_DIR] 
    map[name:APP_VERSION] 
    map[name:APP_COMMIT_SHA] 
    map[name:APP_CRON] 
    map[name:DATABASE_PASSWORD] 
    map[name:MAILER_URL]
    ...
]
```

However, if I execute the same command with the flag `--dry-run`, I do not get any error ( `helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] --dry-run`)

I don't know the reason of this problem or how to solve it

Comment: Could you please run `helm lint` to check if there are any issues with the helm chart? I am analyzing your problem in a meantime.

Comment: Also your `MAILER_URL value` should be put after the `APP_COMMIT_SHA value`. Could you reorder them and tell me if that helped?

Comment: The result of helm lint: `Chart.yaml: icon is recommended 1 chart(s) linted, no failures`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I've found that the reason of this problem was that I had some envVars duplicated. In my deployment I had:

```
...
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      container:
        env:
        - name:  ENV_VAR_NAME
          value: "test"
        - name:  ENV_VAR_NAME
          value: "test"
...
```

After removing the duplicated variable:

```
...
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      container:
        env:
        - name:  ENV_VAR_NAME
          value: "test"
...
```

The `helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART]` worked fine

Comment: some more context here: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6002

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, but no duplicate env variable. I forced the update by doing:

```
helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] --force
```

Comment: In my case it was because the same environment variable was being set via Helm chart template value interpolation.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error but no duplicate variables. Reordering the env vars alphabetically worked for me :-(

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post with an accepted answer, but I'd like to answer the people that reached this post and didn't find duplicate variables, just like me.

If you pass the  `--reuse-values` values flag, you might find this issue too, because helm will reuse the previous values and when a variable changes, instead of replacing, helm might append the variable to the list which in the end leads to the duplicate variable and finally throws the same error.

The workaround is to simply run without the flag.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error fixed via remove duplicated variable.